# Problem opening a SVG in Estlcam

Tags: inkscape, svg

I am having a problem opening in Estlcam an SVG file created by Inkscape. Most SVG files are fine, just a few fail. I've opened the files up in a text editor to try to find out what is different. The ones that work look like standard XML: contain a path like "..." etc. The ones that don't work contain "<image xlink:href..." with what looks like a base64 encoded image.

I have tried selecting the image, then Path -> Object to Path, but I see an error "No objects to convert to path in the selection".
I have tried ungrouping, but see "No groups to ungroup in the selection".

The original image was a bitmap I'm trying to convert into an SVG.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Vector data can have images. Images do not become vector by placing them in a vector editor. they need to either be manually converted (called tracing) or if image is exceptionally clean you can autotrace it. So what your experiencing is indeed how it works.

Comment: There's no way to directly convert raster images to vector. You have 2 options, either redraw it manually using vector tools such as the Pen Tool, or select it and do Path > Trace Bitmap. Note that success with auto tracing is very dependent on the quality and kind of image you have.

Comment: There's a nice tutorial [here on youtube](https://youtu.be/Z39-QaDRHoI?si=Ev3srcPqe__SXwrp) which shows how to use the trace bitmap functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. I was able to figure out what was going on. When "Trace bitmap" Inkscape adds a new layer, the "path". If I delete the original image and leave just the path, it works fine.